# ESP 01 - reset settings to default values

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I set up communication between Arduino UNO and ESP 01 module. ESP replied to AT commands, but sometimes I got result from ESP uncompleted or with wrong characters, so I tried to set AT+IPR=9600, I didnt receive any output to this command and after reboot I only can see random characters on every baudrate, blue diode on ESP shines all the time. Is there any way how I can reset ESP 01 to default settings? Tried to set RESET pin to GND, but it didnt help.

I use remote power supply 3,3V/1A

Pins connected:

```
Vcc = external power supply 3,3V
GND = GND (interconnected bot Arduino and power supply GND)
Tx = Arduino Rx(changed pin to 11 by SoftwareSerial)
Rx = Arduino Tx(changed pin to 10 by SoftwareSerial)
CH_PD - 3,3V
```

Comment: reflashing will reset it

Answer (score 1):

Current ESP-01 firmware versions do not have an `AT+IPR` command. If you're trying to change the ESP's baud rate to use it with SoftwareSerial, the command to do so (in recent versions of the firmware) is: `AT+UART=9600,8,1,0,0` for 9600 baud, 1 stop bit, no parity, no flow control.

The full syntax is:
 `AT+UART=<baudrate>, <databits>, <stopbits>, <parity>, <flow control>`
, where <databits> is the number of data bits per frame, 5,6,7,or 8; <stopbits> is 1, 2, or 3 for 1, 1.5, or 2 stopbits (respectively); <parity> is 0, 1, or 2 for None, Odd, Even (respectively); and <flow control> is 0, 1, 2, or 3 for None, RTS, CTS, RTS and CTS (respectively). Most serial communication and devices that most of us will ever see will be 8 data bits, no parity, and 1 stop bit, abbreviated as "8N1". Flow control is sometimes used, but often it is contained in the data stream itself, such as sending <kbd>Ctl-S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctl-Q</kbd> from the keyboard to manually stop and resume incoming data transmission.

Answer (score 0):

While this technically is not an answer, I can highly suggest the ESP 8266 Arduino library. This way you can program in the Arduino IDE and upload to the ESP module. It's so much faster and efficient than AT commands and because you can see the code in the IDE, you have a better overview of what is happening in the code.

https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino